# Qual a melhor forma de armazenar dados localmente?

Tags: javascript, html, sql, banco-de-dados, aplicação-web

Eu preciso desenvolver um sistema web para rodar sem um servidor, o sistema em questão apenas irá salvar os dados de clientes e agendamentos. Eu não gostaria de utilizar um servidor de banco de dados, pois se torna chato o cliente ter que iniciar o server sempre que for utilizar o sistema. Por isso desejo salvar sem utilizar um server. Eu considerei utilizar JSON mas não me parece muito viável, e também considerei a API IndexedDB, mas ela parece ser muito complicada. Existe alguma outra forma em que o cliente apenas precise abrir o navegador e utilizar o sistema offline ?

Answer (score 1):

Olha, creio que não seja viável, por alguns motivos. Eu conheço 3 formas de armazenar dados localmente:

- No localstorage do navegador
- Em um arquivo .csv
- Em um banco de dados

No localstorage é inviável armazenar esse tipo de dado porque existe um limite de armazenamento que é extremamente baixo(No Chrome acho que é 10mb).

No arquivo .csv(tabela do excel) você também teria que ter um servidor rodando a aplicação e também da muito trabalho.

A melhor opção é você criar um banco de dados! e o cliente não vai precisar abrir o banco toda vez que for utilizar! o banco inicia automaticamente junto com o SO como um processo de segundo plano. Você pode utilizar o host local do cliente pra hospedar o servidor em um container Docker que roda sozinho quando ele liga o computador. (Nunca fiz isso, mas tenho quase certeza que funciona, pesquisa um pouco sobre).

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou fazer como você disse

Comment: Por que você pressupôs que a quantidade de dados que vai ser salva é superior ao limite do localstorage?